# CRC: where to put previous remainder

Tags: c, algorithm, cryptography, crc

Right now I'm writing CRC16 realization with polynomials division and without bit shifts (for educational purposes).

My question is: when I have CRC of previous byte and read new byte where I need to place previous remainder for counting new CRC? (before new byte, after new byte or XOR it with new byte, etc...)

My code works fine for on symbol from text file but it doesn't work with more than one symbol. It seems for me that I put the first remainder to wrong place :)

Full code will placed below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void printBits(uint32_t inbyte, int width) 
{
    char modres = inbyte % 2;
    inbyte = inbyte >> 1;
    if (width > 0) {
        printBits(inbyte, --width);
    }

    printf("%d", modres);
}

struct polynom 
{
    uint8_t x16;uint8_t x15;uint8_t x14;uint8_t x13;uint8_t x12;
    uint8_t x11;uint8_t x10;uint8_t x9;uint8_t x8;uint8_t x7;
    uint8_t x6;uint8_t x5;uint8_t x4;uint8_t x3;uint8_t x2;
    uint8_t x1;uint8_t x0;
};

struct polycrc 
{
    uint8_t x15; uint8_t x14; uint8_t x13; uint8_t x12;
    uint8_t x11; uint8_t x10; uint8_t x9; uint8_t x8; uint8_t x7;
    uint8_t x6; uint8_t x5; uint8_t x4; uint8_t x3; uint8_t x2;
    uint8_t x1; uint8_t x0;
};

struct byte 
{
    uint8_t x7; uint8_t x6; uint8_t x5; uint8_t x4;
    uint8_t x3; uint8_t x2; uint8_t x1; uint8_t x0;
};

void printPolynom(struct polynom inp) 
{
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d",
        inp.x16, inp.x15, inp.x14, inp.x13, inp.x12, inp.x11, inp.x10,
        inp.x9, inp.x8, inp.x7, inp.x6, inp.x5, inp.x4, inp.x3, inp.x2,
        inp.x1, inp.x0);
}

void printCRC(struct polycrc inp)
{
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d",
        inp.x15, inp.x14, inp.x13, inp.x12, inp.x11, inp.x10,
        inp.x9, inp.x8, inp.x7, inp.x6, inp.x5, inp.x4, inp.x3, inp.x2,
        inp.x1, inp.x0);
}

struct polycrc getCRC(uint8_t inByte, struct polycrc inCRC, 
                    struct polynom inp) 
{
    struct delim
    {
        uint8_t xb7, xb6, xb5, xb4, xb3, xb2, xb1, xb0,
            xa15, xa14, xa13, xa12, xa11, xa10, xa9, xa8, xa7,
            xa6, xa5, xa4, xa3, xa2, xa1, xa0;
    };

    struct Bytes
    {
        uint8_t b7; uint8_t b6; uint8_t b5; 
        uint8_t b4; uint8_t b3; uint8_t b2;
        uint8_t b1; uint8_t b0;
    };

    printBits(inByte, 7);
    printf("|");
    printCRC(inCRC);
    printf("\n");

    struct Bytes oneByte;
    oneByte.b0 = inByte % 2; inByte = inByte / 2;
    oneByte.b1 = inByte % 2; inByte = inByte / 2;
    oneByte.b2 = inByte % 2; inByte = inByte / 2;
    oneByte.b3 = inByte % 2; inByte = inByte / 2;
    oneByte.b4 = inByte % 2; inByte = inByte / 2;
    oneByte.b5 = inByte % 2; inByte = inByte / 2;
    oneByte.b6 = inByte % 2; inByte = inByte / 2;
    oneByte.b7 = inByte % 2; inByte = inByte / 2;

    if (oneByte.b7 == 1){
        inCRC.x7 ^= inp.x0; inCRC.x8 ^= inp.x1; inCRC.x9 ^= inp.x2;
        inCRC.x10 ^= inp.x3; inCRC.x11 ^= inp.x4; inCRC.x12 ^= inp.x5;
        inCRC.x13 ^= inp.x6; inCRC.x14 ^= inp.x7; inCRC.x15 ^= inp.x8;
        oneByte.b0 ^= inp.x9; oneByte.b1 ^= inp.x10; oneByte.b2 ^= inp.x11;
        oneByte.b3 ^= inp.x12; oneByte.b4 ^= inp.x13; oneByte.b5 ^= inp.x14;
        oneByte.b6 ^= inp.x15; oneByte.b7 ^= inp.x16;
        inByte = oneByte.b6 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2;
        inByte += oneByte.b5 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2;
        inByte += oneByte.b4 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2;
        inByte += oneByte.b3 * 2 * 2 * 2;
        inByte += oneByte.b2 * 2 * 2;
        inByte += oneByte.b1 * 2;
        inByte += oneByte.b0;

        return getCRC(inByte, inCRC, inp);
    }
    else if (oneByte.b6 == 1){
        inCRC.x6 ^= inp.x0; inCRC.x7 ^= inp.x1; inCRC.x8 ^= inp.x2;
        inCRC.x9 ^= inp.x3; inCRC.x10 ^= inp.x4; inCRC.x11 ^= inp.x5;
        inCRC.x12 ^= inp.x6; inCRC.x13 ^= inp.x7; inCRC.x14 ^= inp.x8;
        inCRC.x15 ^= inp.x9; oneByte.b0 ^= inp.x10; oneByte.b1 ^= inp.x11;
        oneByte.b2 ^= inp.x12; oneByte.b3 ^= inp.x13; oneByte.b4 ^= inp.x14;
        oneByte.b5 ^= inp.x15; oneByte.b6 ^= inp.x16;
        inByte = oneByte.b5 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2;
        inByte += oneByte.b4 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2;
        inByte += oneByte.b3 * 2 * 2 * 2;
        inByte += oneByte.b2 * 2 * 2;
        inByte += oneByte.b1 * 2;
        inByte += oneByte.b0;

        return getCRC(inByte, inCRC, inp);
    }
    else if (oneByte.b5 == 1){
        inCRC.x5 ^= inp.x0; inCRC.x6 ^= inp.x1; inCRC.x7 ^= inp.x2;
        inCRC.x8 ^= inp.x3; inCRC.x9 ^= inp.x4; inCRC.x10 ^= inp.x5;
        inCRC.x11 ^= inp.x6; inCRC.x12 ^= inp.x7; inCRC.x13 ^= inp.x8;
        inCRC.x14 ^= inp.x9; inCRC.x15 ^= inp.x10; oneByte.b0 ^= inp.x11;
        oneByte.b1 ^= inp.x12; oneByte.b2 ^= inp.x13; oneByte.b3 ^= inp.x14;
        oneByte.b4 ^= inp.x15; oneByte.b5 ^= inp.x16;
        inByte = oneByte.b4 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2;
        inByte += oneByte.b3 * 2 * 2 * 2;
        inByte += oneByte.b2 * 2 * 2;
        inByte += oneByte.b1 * 2;
        inByte += oneByte.b0;

        return getCRC(inByte, inCRC, inp);
    }
    else if (oneByte.b4 == 1){
        inCRC.x4 ^= inp.x0; inCRC.x5 ^= inp.x1; inCRC.x6 ^= inp.x2;
        inCRC.x7 ^= inp.x3; inCRC.x8 ^= inp.x4; inCRC.x9 ^= inp.x5;
        inCRC.x10 ^= inp.x6; inCRC.x11 ^= inp.x7; inCRC.x12 ^= inp.x8;
        inCRC.x13 ^= inp.x9; inCRC.x14 ^= inp.x10; inCRC.x15 ^= inp.x11;
        oneByte.b0 ^= inp.x12; oneByte.b1 ^= inp.x13; oneByte.b2 ^= inp.x14;
        oneByte.b3 ^= inp.x15; oneByte.b4 ^= inp.x16;
        inByte = oneByte.b3 * 2 * 2 * 2;
        inByte += oneByte.b2 * 2 * 2;
        inByte += oneByte.b1 * 2;
        inByte += oneByte.b0;

        return getCRC(inByte, inCRC, inp);
    }
    else if (oneByte.b3 == 1){
        inCRC.x3 ^= inp.x0; inCRC.x4 ^= inp.x1; inCRC.x5 ^= inp.x2;
        inCRC.x6 ^= inp.x3; inCRC.x7 ^= inp.x4; inCRC.x8 ^= inp.x5;
        inCRC.x9 ^= inp.x6; inCRC.x10 ^= inp.x7; inCRC.x11 ^= inp.x8;
        inCRC.x12 ^= inp.x9; inCRC.x13 ^= inp.x10; inCRC.x14 ^= inp.x11;
        inCRC.x15 ^= inp.x12; oneByte.b0 ^= inp.x13; oneByte.b1 ^= inp.x14;
        oneByte.b2 ^= inp.x15; oneByte.b3 ^= inp.x16;
        inByte = oneByte.b2 * 2 * 2;
        inByte += oneByte.b1 * 2;
        inByte += oneByte.b0;

        return getCRC(inByte, inCRC, inp);
    }
    else if (oneByte.b2 == 1){
        inCRC.x2 ^= inp.x0; inCRC.x3 ^= inp.x1; inCRC.x4 ^= inp.x2;
        inCRC.x5 ^= inp.x3; inCRC.x6 ^= inp.x4; inCRC.x7 ^= inp.x5;
        inCRC.x8 ^= inp.x6; inCRC.x9 ^= inp.x7; inCRC.x10 ^= inp.x8;
        inCRC.x11 ^= inp.x9; inCRC.x12 ^= inp.x10; inCRC.x13 ^= inp.x11;
        inCRC.x14 ^= inp.x12; inCRC.x15 ^= inp.x13; oneByte.b0 ^= inp.x14;
        oneByte.b1 ^= inp.x15; oneByte.b2 ^= inp.x16;
        inByte = oneByte.b1 * 2;
        inByte += oneByte.b0;

        return getCRC(inByte, inCRC, inp);
    }
    else if (oneByte.b1 == 1){
        inCRC.x1 ^= inp.x0; inCRC.x2 ^= inp.x1; inCRC.x3 ^= inp.x2;
        inCRC.x4 ^= inp.x3; inCRC.x5 ^= inp.x4; inCRC.x6 ^= inp.x5;
        inCRC.x7 ^= inp.x6; inCRC.x8 ^= inp.x7; inCRC.x9 ^= inp.x8;
        inCRC.x10 ^= inp.x9; inCRC.x11 ^= inp.x10; inCRC.x12 ^= inp.x11;
        inCRC.x13 ^= inp.x12; inCRC.x14 ^= inp.x13; inCRC.x15 ^= inp.x14;
        oneByte.b0 ^= inp.x15; oneByte.b1 ^= inp.x16;
        inByte = oneByte.b0;

        return getCRC(inByte, inCRC, inp);
    }
    else if (oneByte.b0 == 1){
        inCRC.x0 ^= inp.x0; inCRC.x1 ^= inp.x1; inCRC.x2 ^= inp.x2;
        inCRC.x3 ^= inp.x3; inCRC.x4 ^= inp.x4; inCRC.x5 ^= inp.x5;
        inCRC.x6 ^= inp.x6; inCRC.x7 ^= inp.x7; inCRC.x8 ^= inp.x8;
        inCRC.x9 ^= inp.x9; inCRC.x10 ^= inp.x10; inCRC.x11 ^= inp.x11;
        inCRC.x12 ^= inp.x12; inCRC.x13 ^= inp.x13; inCRC.x14 ^= inp.x14;
        inCRC.x15 ^= inp.x15; oneByte.b0 ^= inp.x16;

        inByte = 0;

        return getCRC(inByte, inCRC, inp);
    }
    else {
        return inCRC;
    }
}

int main()
{
    //  Initializing polynomial
    struct polynom p;
    p.x16 = 1; p.x15 = 1; p.x2 = 1; p.x0 = 1;
    p.x14 = 0; p.x13 = 0; p.x12 = 0; p.x11 = 0; p.x10 = 0; p.x9 = 0;
    p.x8 = 0; p.x7 = 0; p.x6 = 0; p.x5 = 0; p.x4 = 0;
    p.x3 = 0; p.x1 = 0;

    // Initializing CRC
    struct polycrc crc;
    crc.x15 = 0; crc.x14 = 0; crc.x13 = 0; crc.x12 = 0; crc.x11 = 0;
    crc.x10 = 0; crc.x9 = 0; crc.x8 = 0; crc.x7 = 0; crc.x6 = 0;
    crc.x5 = 0; crc.x4 = 0; crc.x3 = 0; crc.x2 = 0; crc.x1 = 0;
    crc.x0 = 0;

    //  Print p and crc to check
    printPolynom(p);
    printf("\n");
    printCRC(crc);
    printf("\n");

    char* inFileName = "input1.txt";
    FILE* inputFile;
    uint8_t c = 0;

    fopen_s(&inputFile, inFileName, "r");

    if (inputFile == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file %s", inFileName);
        return 1;
    }

    //  Read file and count CRC
    c = fgetc(inputFile);
    while (!feof(inputFile)) {
        crc = getCRC(c, crc, p);
        printf("Byte %0x CRC: ", c);
        printCRC(crc);
        printf("\n");
        c = fgetc(inputFile);
    }
    fclose(inputFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use arrays here instead of your awkward structs?

Comment: Aren't the redundancy bits embedded into the codeword? Not placed in front or behind the codeword.

Comment: Please try to use one of several recognized formatting styles - your code is completely unparsable!

Comment: Did you read [this text](http://ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt)? It should answer nearly all questions around CRC.

Comment: To @Jabberwocky: I use this just for fun while I'm learning structures :)

Comment: @AlexT that's a very poor usage of `struct`. A `struct` is simply not appropriate here.

Comment: To @thebusybee: really I'm not so deep in C and hope to find help here... As i can see the text always goes to lokkup tables and it is not for me in this case.
As I can see from this code https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showcode/295.php CRC of previos block is provided to procedure for counting CRC of the next block. May be I'm the noob, but I can't realize this algorythm with polynomials :)

Comment: My code counts CRC16 for one byte totally the same as https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showcode/295.php But i really can't realize which way is right for counting CRC of 2nd and next bytes with previous CRC.

Comment: To @Jabberwocky if i'll rewrite it with arrays the question about place for previous remainder will be actual too. Am I wrong?

Comment: Well, if you look through the text just for the pictures, you will see that there is not that **one** CRC algorithm. So some or all of your options "before new byte, after new byte or XOR it with new byte, etc..." might be right, depending on which algorithm you want.

Comment: @AlexT yes that won't change that problem

Comment: This code can neither read nor salvaged, I'm afraid. Just look at CRC16 implementations, there's plenty of them to be found on the net (some are even correct). Should be roughly 10-20 LoC and maybe some look-up tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle the CRC sequence one byte at a time, the sequence is xor an input byte with the upper (if left shift) or lower (if right shift) 8 bits of the CRC, then cycle the 16 bit CRC like a linear feedback shift register 8 times using the CRC polynomial for the feedback. This can be sped up using a 256 entry lookup table. The question is asking for a hardware like solution that maps an uncycled 16 bit input CRC into an 8 cycled 16 bit output CRC using bit field structures.

The mapping is a binary linear mapping (like a binary (and, xor) matrix multiply with a 16 by 16 bit matrix), and the ordering doesn't matter. A set of 16 equations, each xoring a sub set of the uncycled CRC bits, into a cycled CRC bit can be used. The equations can be created by using a conventional method to cycle a CRC 8 times, for a set of 16 input CRC values, each with 1 bit set: {0x0001, 0x0002, 0x0004, ..., 0x2000, 0x4000, 0x8000} and noting which input bits contribute to each output bit.

Example for a left shifting CRC with polynomial 0x11021, for each byte of input:

```
    /* xor the input byte to the upper 8 bits of the CRC */
    crcin.b8 ^= dat.b0;
    crcin.b9 ^= dat.b1;
    crcin.ba ^= dat.b2;
    crcin.bb ^= dat.b3;
    crcin.bc ^= dat.b4;
    crcin.bd ^= dat.b5;
    crcin.be ^= dat.b6;
    crcin.bf ^= dat.b7;
    /* cycle the 16 bit CRC 8 times via mapping */
    crcot.b0 = crcin.b8 ^ crcin.bc;
    crcot.b1 = crcin.b9 ^ crcin.bd;
    crcot.b2 = crcin.ba ^ crcin.be;
    crcot.b3 = crcin.bb ^ crcin.bf;
    crcot.b4 = crcin.bc;
    crcot.b5 = crcin.b8 ^ crcin.bc ^ crcin.bd;
    crcot.b6 = crcin.b9 ^ crcin.bd ^ crcin.be;
    crcot.b7 = crcin.ba ^ crcin.be ^ crcin.bf;
    crcot.b8 = crcin.b0 ^ crcin.bb ^ crcin.bf;
    crcot.b9 = crcin.b1 ^ crcin.bc;
    crcot.ba = crcin.b2 ^ crcin.bd;
    crcot.bb = crcin.b3 ^ crcin.be;
    crcot.bc = crcin.b4 ^ crcin.b8 ^ crcin.bc ^ crcin.bf;
    crcot.bd = crcin.b5 ^ crcin.b9 ^ crcin.bd;
    crcot.be = crcin.b6 ^ crcin.ba ^ crcin.be;
    crcot.bf = crcin.b7 ^ crcin.bb ^ crcin.bf;
    crcin = crcot;
```

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your help and your time wasted to compose such answer to my question. And it was really helpful! :) Thanks again!

Comment: @AlexT - this is pretty much how it could be implemented in hardware, except that the first 8 and last 16 equations could be done in parallel, just waiting for propagation delay through the gates, for the output to crcot to stabilize, then a second cycle to transfer back to crcin.